# Is "What does it mean by [something]?" a correct utterance?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

If I said to you "What does it mean by liberty?" or "what does the text mean by liberty?" would the question be correct in structure, meaning and grammar?

I was told that "it" or "the text" cannot MEAN something, but I am still doubtful

Answer (score 3):

Both of those forms are correct, and are exactly how a native speaker would ask for clarification or further meaning on a word or topic.

Comment: I would add that "the text" was written or spoken by someone, so a more common variant of this might be, "What does the author mean by liberty?" or "What do they mean by liberty?" Since the question was tagged meaning-in-context (and it doesn't give much context), that is the most common context that I can think of.

Comment: I have a similar question regarding this topic. Take this scenario for example, assume I am an English teacher in some non-English speaking country, and I am asking my student what the word "newspaper" means. Is it correct if I say: `What does it mean by "newspaper"?`